# Include values of \ref, \eqref into a new document

Tags: cross-referencing, external-files, thesis

I have an introduction to my thesis. It includes a lot of constructions like `in Section \ref{sec1} is shown` or `the formula is given in \eqref{eq1}` whereas the corresponding Section and equation are in the separate files. Everything works fine and I have a correct pdf with explicit numbers, say, "in Section 3.2" or "is given in (5.3)" instead of `\ref` and `\eqref`.

For some reasons, I nead to have this introduction as a separate document. However, I still need to have the explicit numbers in proper places. Hence, my question is the following: is it possible to obtain from the existing thesis a new tex-document which will have instead of `\ref{Sec1}` its value "3.2" and so on?

Comment: It seems that the [`xr` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xr) is what you need.

Comment: Welcome to the site! @Jubobs an answer? Or can you find a duplicate?